# When i create an angular project, it is not getting built successfully?

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I reinstalled windows recently and have been facing this issue with angular since then.
My old projects are running fine, but when I create new project I am getting the following error.
I have tried to install angular CLI and Node.js again, I also reinstalled VS code.
I have tried adding the paths in the tsconfig.app.json file.
At this point, I am totally clueless.

---

PS D:\C#LTI\WebApi\new_project_angular> ng build
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Warning: ▲ [WARNING] Comments in CSS use "/* ... */" instead of "//"

```
D:/C#LTI/WebApi/new_project_angular/src/app/app.component.css:1:18:
  1 │ /******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
    ╵                   ~~
```

Warning: ▲ [WARNING] Unexpected "("

```
D:/C#LTI/WebApi/new_project_angular/src/app/app.component.css:1:9:
  1 │ /******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
    ╵          ^
```

../../../C#LTI/WebApi/new_project_angular/src/environments/environment.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: D:\C#LTI\WebApi\new_project_angular\src\environments\environment.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
at D:\C#LTI\WebApi\new_project_angular\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:64:26

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:/C#LTI/WebApi/new_project_angular/src/app/app.component.css?ngResource' in 'D:\C#LTI\WebApi\new_project_angular'

Error: The loader "D:/C#LTI/WebApi/new_project_angular/src/app/app.component.css" didn't return a string.

Comment: I'm going to assume the `#` character in your folder structure is causing the problem. Try creating a test project in another folder, if that one finishes correctly, try removing or replacing the `#` character with another.

Comment: Yes, when I removed the "#" character it worked.